# How to change text color and final random variable?

Tags: java, random

For Java class I have to make a simple Guess the letter game, I wanted to set the letter to be random using a string, but for the class this needs to be a final variable. How do I do this? 
Also the word needs to be orange Text. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.util.Random;


public class PracTestRand{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Random r = new Random();
    String secret = "";
    secret = (secret + (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
    String stop = "go";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Guess the secret letter!\n");



    while (stop.equalsIgnoreCase("go")){

        System.out.print("Enter a word ('stop' to end): ");

        String word = sc.nextLine();


        if (word.contains(secret)){
           System.out.println("That contains the secret letter!");

        }   

        else { 
        System.out.println("Your word does not contain the secret letter!");

        } 

        if (word.equals(secret)){
            System.out.println("You guessed the secret letter!\nThanks!");
            stop = "stop";
        }

        if (word.equals("stop")){
            stop = "stop";
            System.out.println("Thanks!");
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: You can not (portably) assign colors to text that is printed with `System.out.println`. Additionally, I don't see any `final` variable, or what the question actually is about. Maybe you can elaborate this further.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want `secret` to be `final`. Note that the `final` allows for a variable to be initialized, so just make sure you initialize it with the value you want as `final`.

```
final String value;
value = "Your final string";
```

In your case:

```
final String secret;
secret = String.valueOf((char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
```

Or in one line:

```
final String secret = String.valueOf((char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
```

It's not possible to use colors when using `System.out.print()` or `System.out.println()`. If colouring is a requirement you may have to consider developing a GUI using [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

---

Also, the code you have provided has several issues, consider the comments below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class PracTestRand{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Random r = new Random();
    //Just make it a one-line statement and final will give you no problem.
    final String secret = String.valueOf((char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
    //You are using a String as a boolean ("stop" -> false & "go" -> true).
    boolean keepPlaying = true;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Use println() here instead of print() + "\n"
    System.out.println("Guess the secret letter!");
    while (keepPlaying) {
        System.out.print("Enter a word ('stop' to end): ");
        String word = sc.nextLine();
        /*
         * Control flow - It seems you only want one of the statements to
         * be executed per iteration, use 'else if' to make sure 
         * only one is executed.
         * I've also replaced equals() with equalsIgnoreCase()
         * and added toLowerCase()
         * This allows you to play the game with upper case letters.
         */
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")){
            System.out.println("Thanks!");
            keepPlaying = false;
        }
        else if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(secret)){
            System.out.println("You guessed the secret letter!");
            System.out.println("Thanks!");
            keepPlaying = false;
        }
        else if (word.toLowerCase().contains(secret)){
           System.out.println("That contains the secret letter!");
        }   
        else { 
            System.out.println("Your word does not contain the secret letter!");
        } 
    } 
    //It's recommended practice to close the Scanner after you are done
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy! Thats some great help for a beginner! :)